# What is the correct format to capitalize an Input?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make the command being input capitalize the first letter so that it matches the items in the command list regardless of if the user input is case sensitive.

toupper()
capitalize()

```
command_list = ["Show", "Grab", "Edit", "Drop", "Exit"]
command = input("Choose a command:\t")
command = (command)
items = ["Wooden Staff", "Wizard Hat", "Cloth Shoes"]
grab = ["Poition of Invis", "Granite Platebody", "Water Bottle"]


if command in command_list:
    if command == command_list[0]:
        print("These are your current Items")
        print(items)
```

Answer (score 0):

> so that it matches the items in the command list regardless of if the user input is case sensitive

Rather than trying to modify the user input to match the expected capitalization, just coerce both the user input and the valid commands to lowercase, and then compare:

```py
if command.lower() == command_list[0].lower():
    print("These are your current Items")
    print(items)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seing any purpose of saving the commands capitalized, so the best approach to follow is to save your list items in lower-case and comparing whatever input with them as follows.

```
command_list = ["show", "grab", "edit", "drop", "exit"]
command = input("Choose a command:\t")
command = (command)
items = ["Wooden Staff", "Wizard Hat", "Cloth Shoes"]
grab = ["Poition of Invis", "Granite Platebody", "Water Bottle"]


if command.lower() in command_list:
    if command.lower() == command_list[0]:
        print("These are your current Items")
        print(items)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to have the 1st letter capitalized for some reason, you can try:

```
command = input("Choose a command:\t")
command = command.lower().capitalize()
```

I hope it helps.